# Error Implementing " Upload Task for a Multi-Part Request" using afnetworking 2.1.0

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking

Afnetworking 2.1 - I am trying to create an Upload Task for a Multi-Part Request. I am using the sample code given by Mattt in the documentation.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"http://example.com/upload" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"file://path/to/image.jpg"] name:@"file" fileName:@"filename.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg" error:nil];
} error:nil];

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
NSProgress *progress = nil;

NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request progress:&progress completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@ %@", response, responseObject);
    }
}];

[uploadTask resume];
```

I keep getting this error and i have no clue why.

```
Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x8ac1a00 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set., NSUnderlyingError=0x8ac1100 "Request failed: unacceptable (406)"}
```

Thank you. Any Help is appreciable.

Comment: is this the code you are running or you just paste in here the code from the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things are happening:

1. Your server is rejecting your HTTP request with [HTTP status code 406](https://www.google.com/search?q=http%20406).
2. The body of the response is not valid JSON.

Before you continue, you may wish to install [AFNetworkActivityLogger](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityLogger) in your project so you can more easily inspect the network requests while debugging.

As far as #1, the reason for this depends on the semantics of your server.  There may be a clue in `responseObject`.  If `NSURLResponse *response` is of the type `NSHTTPURLResponse`, you could also inspect the headers (`allHeaderFields`) for a clue.  You can also consult API documentation, or whoever wrote the server, to figure out why a 406 may be returned.

For #2 - AFURLSessionManager by default uses [`AFJSONResponseSerializer`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.1.0/Classes/AFJSONResponseSerializer.html) to parse the server's response.  If the server's response won't be in JSON, you may need to use a different serializer.  If it may come in multiple formats, you need to create an `AFCompoundResponseSerializer` which handles JSON, and any other formats that your server might return.

Finally, if you're using HTTP, you probably want to use `AFHTTPSessionManager` instead of `AFURLSessionManager`.

Comment: can you explain why, I too just followed the sample in the docs. -- "Finally, if you're using HTTP, you probably want to use AFHTTPSessionManager instead of AFURLSessionManager."

Comment: @Bek It's not a big deal, but it offers some convenience methods that can simplify your code. The biggest help is the request serializer, which isn't available on the URL session manager.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I will check out the documentation some more, I like convenience methods, and especially the request serializer since that is a frequent problem I have when implementing AFNetworking.